# Clion is creating a file .idea/.name. What is this used for?

Tags: clion

Clion is creating a file .idea/.name. What is this used for?

It seems to be a Cmake project name. And if the CmakeLists.txt has multiple projects in it, it's the last project.

The odd thing is that the "Recent Projects" list contains that name in the list. So if I have multiple repos with the same project name then it gets confused (and confuses me).

I have tried deleting it, but Clion recreates it. Which brings up the question of how to prevent this file from being created.

Note that Pycharm doesn't have this. It looks Clion specific.